# What is the code to get the download link for a product in WooCommerce?

Tags: post-meta, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to add the direct download link of a product to a button, but I'm stuck.

What I tried is this

```
<a href="<?php echo $product->downloadable_files; ?>">Download</a>
```

And of course it didn't work.

What is the proper code to get the product's download url?

Comment: Note that you should never output the actual downloadable file to a user, but instead grant the user permissions on a downloadable, and output that permissions link. Like this, a user can share a link to a downloadable that does not require authentication.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the code to get the download link for a downloadable product in WooCommerce.

```
$downloads = $product->get_downloads();

foreach( $downloads as $key => $each_download ) {
  echo '<a href="'.$each_download["file"].'">Download</a>';
}
```

Comment: Your code works. It only needs a closing to the echo: ...Download</a>';

Comment: get_files() is now deprecated so users should use get_downloads(); you can update your comment

Comment: hi can you please guide me lit bit where i need to write this code? in theme functions.php or in any other file ?