# Woocommerce product download URL

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm making a skin for The Grid plugin (https://theme-one.com/docs/the-grid/#developer_guide).

All the products are virtual and downloadable — I've managed to make an add to cart function, but need to download products instantly too. Is there a meta key for the file url (combed the database and couldn't spot one) or a way to get it?

Currently I've got something that just returns an array:

```
$output .= '<p><a href="' . $tg_el->get_item_meta('_downloadable_files') . '" download target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download Image</a></p>';
```

Thought I'd found a possible solution: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/199884/134263 but am not great with php and I'm unsure how to implement it.

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php $downloads = $product->get_files();
        foreach( $downloads as $key => $download ) {
            echo '<p class="download-link"><a href="' . esc_url( $download['file'] ) . '">' . $download['name'] . '</a></p>';
        } ?>
```

Check this.. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php                                           
    $downloads = $product->get_files();
    foreach( $downloads as $key => $each_download ) {
        echo '<p><a href="'.$each_download["file"].'" download><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download Image</a></p>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: use get_downloads() instead of get_files().  get_files() is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

as i used @dannie Herdyawans code snippet, it shows that `get_files()` function is deprecated.
so instead of that use `get_downloads()` function. listed below example.

```
$downloads = $productObj->get_downloads();
if ($downloads):
    foreach ($downloads as $key => $each_download) {
        $product->productDownloadUrl = $each_download['file'];
        $product->productDownloadName = $each_download['name'];
    }
endif;
```